# webrtc, how to use IMAGE, instead video

Tags: video, webrtc

I make WEBRTC Video chat, test page.
and

our client say, I don't want show my face.  so , we need to camera off and 
send other image, or something else.

how to do that?

Comment: How were you able to display images after the client muted video??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### There are many possible cases:

1. Setup **audio-only** connection
2. Setup **audio/video** connection however **disable video-tracks**
3. Setup **audio/video** connection however **change video-mLine's attribute "sendrecv" to "inactive"**
4. Setup **audio/video** connection; keep sending video however on target user's side, either **remove "src"** or **hide video-element** or **use invisible video element**.

It seems that first options suits your needs.

#### Setting-up audio-only connection is as easy as:

1. Invoking `getUserMedia` with `{audio:true}` and adding `MediaStream` to peer connection.
2. While invoking `createOffer/createAnswer` methods; setting `OfferToReceiveAudio:true` however `OfferToReceiveVideo:false` - *Remember, both are true by default.*

---

**P.S.** *Audio-only connection still works if you set `OfferToReceiveVideo:true`.*

---

#### To share users' snapshot; obviously you can either use XMLHttpRequest/DB or WebSocket/etc. to exchange `Data-URLs` among users.

---

It is possible to set `poster` of video-element; however make sure that you've not set `src` at the same time; otherwise `poster` will fail.